# ActionScript 3 - Draw two shapes on the same movie clip's graphics avoiding alpha blending between them

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, alphablending

for example:

```
var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.5);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
mc.graphics.endFill();

mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.5);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
mc.graphics.endFill();
```

with this i will get a box with an alpha value darker than 0.5. I want a 0.5 alpha square without using something like:

```
var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
mc.graphics.endFill();

mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
mc.graphics.endFill();

var bmp:BitmapData=new BitmapData(100,100);
bmp.draw(mc);
var mc2:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
mc2.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bmp);
mc2.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
mc2.graphics.endFill();
```

obvoiusly i don´t want it for drawing squares, it´s for a shadow casting algorithm i´m working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, you can just draw everything as alpha 1, set the alpha of the object itself to 0.5, and then use a LAYER blending mode which flattens the transparency before applying the alpha.

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mc);

var sp:Shape;

sp = new Shape();
sp.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
sp.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
sp.graphics.endFill();
mc.addChild(sp);

sp = new Shape();
sp.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
sp.graphics.drawRect(50,50,100,100);
sp.graphics.endFill();
mc.addChild(sp);

mc.alpha = 0.5;
mc.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
```

It's a bit convoluted, but you get the idea.

Using a bitmap would be the best for performance, though. Again, it depends on exactly what you have to implement and how.

Also, depending on what you have to draw, if you can rely on [drawPath()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawPath%28%29) instead, you could just use it with winding set to [GraphicsPathWinding.NON_ZERO](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/flash10drawingapi/).

Comment: Wow!, yes, this is what i was looking for, but is pretty slow, 6 fps compared with the 35 fps of bitmapdata D:

Comment: setting cacheAsBitmap on the parent will probably bring them up to par performance wise, unless you're rotating and scaling alot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using alpha ,you could use ColorTransform. With TweenMax , it's pretty easy but of course you could code your own solution.

```
var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff); mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100); mc.graphics.endFill();
TweenMax.to( mc , 0 , {colorTransform:{tint:0x000000 , tintAmount:.5}} );

mc.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff); mc.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100); mc.graphics.endFill();
TweenMax.to( mc , 0 , {colorTransform:{tint:0x000000 , tintAmount:.5}} );
```

Comment: hi, aplying a colorTransform didn´t work. mc.transform.colorTransform=new ColorTransform(1,1,1,.5); produces the same result as before... perhaps there is no way to change the way that flash manages alpha

Comment: Doing it like this is the same as setting the alpha property to .5 , this is why I used TweenMax (greensock.com) as a shortcut to changing the amount of color.

Comment: mmh yes, you are right :) ... but i realized that rendering the entire sprite on a bitmap and then modify the alpha with copypixels and an alphabitmap is faster than render the sprite itself (my app is running at 2x zoom using a 375x275 canvas)